# how to make text field readonly upon selection of value from drop down list html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to make text field read only based on user selection from drop down list

Here is my code

```
<select id="Personal_Religion_Sect" name="Personal_Religion_Sect">
    <option value="Un-Married"></option>
    <option value="Married"></option>

<select>
```

When User selects `Un-Married` from datalist then I want to make the input `readonly`

```
<label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label> <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Medical_Category" id = "Medical_Category"   style = "color:  black;" value="<?php echo $data['Personal_Medical_Category'];?>" required placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable"/>
```

and If user selects `Married` from datalist then I want to set the input to `readonly=false`

How would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also worth noting that your `<label>` tag is referencing a different element than your input. Should be `for="Medical_Category"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this through PHP, you'll need to do this in JavaScript.

The below snippet would include jQuery, then add a listener to your select - where when changed, it checks for the new  value, and if the value is equal to `Married`, it removes the `required` attribute, and adds the `readonly` attribute. These are inverted when a different value than `Married` is selected.

```js
$("#Personal_Religion_Sect").on("change", function() {
  var input = $("#Medical_Category");
  var readonly = !(this.value === "Married");

  input.prop("readonly", readonly);
  input.prop("required", !readonly);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Personal_Religion_Sect" name="Personal_Religion_Sect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select one --</option>
    <option value="Un-Married">Un-Married</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
<select>

<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label> 
<input type="text" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       class="form-control"  
       name="Medical_Category" 
       id="Medical_Category" 
       style="color:  black;" 
       value="<?php echo $data['Personal_Medical_Category'];?>" 
       required 
       placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" 
       data-toggle="tooltip" 
       title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable"/>
```